# Remove GridViewRow from jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

From my `gridview "gridPayments"` am trying to delete Payments by using the `PaymentId`, and also am trying to delete the selected gridview row, for this am calling the jQuery function, which is in the `custom.js` file, from my aspx script page like,

```
<div class="close1" onclick="DeletePayment(<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>,
                                             <%# Eval("PaymentId") %>);"></div>
```

and in the DeletePayment method am receiving these valus as

```
function DeletePayment(index,paymentid) {
//my code for deleting payment..
}
```

with the `paymentid` I can delete the payment by calling the webservice from my jQuery, the problem is I want to `refresh the GridView after the successful deletion of Payment`.

I tried like deleting the gridview row from this method like

```
index.remove();
```

but its not working, I dunno how to remove the gridviewrow from this jQuery method...can anyone help me here....

Comment: jQuery runs at the client and doesn't know anything about GridViews, it only knows about HTML tables.

Comment: thanks Steve, for ur repsonse

Answer (score 1):

One way would be this:

Have a method in your code-behind to refresh the GridView's content:

```
public void LoadGridViewData(){ // Blah... }
```

On the aspx page, have an ASP.NET Button which, when clicked, will call the GridView data refresh method.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnRefreshData" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="btnRefreshData_OnClick />
```

Now create the button click method in the code-behind:

```
public void btnRefreshData_OnClick(object sender, Eventargs e)
{
    LoadGridViewData(); // This does the data binding stuff on the GridView.
}
```

Finally, use this Javascript to hook up the button click when deleting data:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function DeletePayment(index,paymentid) {
       // Do your deletion, and then finally.....
       $("#btnRefreshData").click(); // This will call the server-side button click method.
    }
</script>
```

Now I'm not sure if the above is 100%, as I'm doing this from memory, but the overall idea is sound.